# Read a file backwords line by line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to read my file line by line from the end. I tried `tac` but that works like `cat` and I want to access it line by line.

Is there a way to do that in bash?

Comment: You have asked few questions so far (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2813853/user2813853?tab=questions) that got some answer and just accepted one. Remember you can do so to indicate your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tac`... together with a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   echo "line is: $line"
done < <(tac file)
```

#### Test

```
$ seq 5 > a
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "line is: $line"; done < <(tac a)
line is: 5
line is: 4
line is: 3
line is: 2
line is: 1
```